Azure Service Bus seems to use HTTP long polling instead of AMQP
In our application, we use MassTransit and Azure Service Bus. Configuration code looks like this:
x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
{
    var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("AzureServiceBusEndpoint")
                           ?? throw new Bug("Service bus configuration is missing");
    cfg.Host(
    new UriBuilder("sb", new Uri(connectionString).Host).Uri,
                   configurator => configurator.TokenCredential = credential);
    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
});

Functionally everything works fine, but in dependencies tracking I see regular HTTPS requests to the ASB host per each configured topic that last for 60 seconds and then repeated. I expected the application to communicate with ASB through the AMQP protocol and maintain a long-living TCP connection.
What am I missing here? Is it a configuration issue and I just missed some option to enable AMQP?
The dependency traces (thousands of them!) that I see in Application Insights look like this:
timestamp: 2024-07-26T10:00:59.3023196Z
id: b27b6a75a8991bee
target: ourservername-asb-dev.servicebus.windows.net/WorkItemStageChangedNotification
type: Azure Service Bus
name: ServiceBusReceiver.Receive
success: True
duration: 59997.8184
performanceBucket: 30sec-1min
itemType: dependency
customDimensions: {"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Staging","_MS.ProcessedByMetricExtractors":"(Name:'Dependencies', Ver:'1.1')"}
operation_Id: c87b305ea70a107ddb66407c4242e3e1
operation_ParentId: c87b305ea70a107ddb66407c4242e3e1
application_Version: 8.0
client_Type: PC
client_IP: 0.0.0.0
client_City: Boydton
client_StateOrProvince: Virginia
client_CountryOrRegion: United States
cloud_RoleName: notifications-dev
cloud_RoleInstance: noti_951344198b
sdkVersion: dotnetc:2.21.0-429
itemId: 2e6eebf2-4b36-11ef-94c2-000d3a04ebf3
itemCount: 1


Maybe the Azure SDK is falling back to web sockets because it can't get an AMQP connection through a firewall? AMQP is the default, so I'm not sure why it resort to long polling.

It's always AMQP. The transport is either TCP or WebSockets. For WebSockets to be used, the current SDK requires explicit configuration. The old SDK used to auto-detect and fail over. What SDK is used? (NuGet Package).

The SDK package is Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus 7.17.0

Confirming Sean's statement.   The Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package supports only AMQP whether using raw TCP or websockets as the transport.

I added the sample trace to the original question. Given the AMQP-only nature of Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus, what could be the reason for these traces?

That trace is a read attempt.   I don't have an understanding of which SDK client MassTransit uses nor their usage pattern - but that trace is only emitted when a receive operation takes place.  Could be a direct call, could be part of a read+dispatch loop depending on the client.   If you collect a slice of Azure SDK logs over a 2-5 minute period, I could tell you more.  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging

Turns out that these requests are not HTTP long-polling despite looking very similar. Telemetry instrumentation for ASB logs every heartbeat as a dependency. Here is one potential work-around: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/440864/asb-application-insights-excessive-dependency-logg
